Vitest + @testing-library/react Issue
currently I’m stuck on this one. so i'm implementing a unit test in my turbo repo app with react remix and i'm creating a unit test for this component
/apps/my-portal/routes/signin.forgot.jsx
import { Link } from "@remix-run/react";
import { Trans } from "@lingui/macro";

export default function ForgotPassword() {
  return (
    <>
      <Trans>
        <h1>Forgot Password?</h1>
        <p>Add the forgot password page here.</p>
        <p>It should should handle the flow for resetting a forgotten password</p>
      </Trans>
      <Link to="/signin"><Trans>Sign in</Trans></Link>
    </>
  );
}

and this is my unit test code
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import { MemoryRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import ForgotPassword from '../signin.forgot.jsx';
import { describe, it, expect } from 'vitest';

describe('ForgotPassword component', () => {
  it('renders Forgot Password page', () => {
    render(
      <MemoryRouter>
        <ForgotPassword />
      </MemoryRouter>
    );

    expect(screen.getByRole('heading', { name: /forgot password/i })).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(screen.getByText(/add the forgot password page here/i)).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(screen.getByText(/it should should handle the flow for resetting a forgotten password/i)).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(screen.getByRole('link', { name: /sign in/i })).toHaveAttribute('href', '/signin');
  });
});

when i execute the npx vitest run i always get this error and already have check everything and i seem to don't know the clue
SyntaxError: Identifier 'prevRefreshReg' has already been declared
 ❯ new Script node:vm:116:7
 ❯ createScript node:vm:268:10
 ❯ Object.runInThisContext node:vm:316:10
 ❯ app/routes/_test__/signin.forgot.test.jsx:4:31
      2| import { MemoryRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
      3| import ForgotPassword from '../signin.forgot.jsx';
      4| import { describe, it, expect } from 'vitest';
       |                               ^
      5| 
      6| describe('ForgotPassword component', () => {

